# How do I consume file which has date and time in it using Apache Camel?

Tags: date, time, apache-camel

I would like to consume file from a directory which matches the below pattern

**File Pattern:** InputFile_yymmdd_HHmmss.csv

How do I specify the pattern **yymmdd_HHmmss** in Apache Camel?

Please Note: I am not using XML based route in Camel. My sample code looks in the below mentioned format.

```
from("file:src/main/resources/csv/InputFile_yymmdd_HHmmss.csv").log(loggingLevel.INFO, "File Read")
```

Any sample code would solve my problem.

The route is not getting initialised when I use the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Camel File](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) component supports an `include` property that can define a regex pattern for files.

```
from("file:src/main/resources/csv?include=InputFile_\\d{6}_\\d{6}\.csv")
  .log(loggingLevel.INFO, "File Read")
```